# python and cdll in the ctypes. cannot use the printf

Tags: python, printf, ctypes

I'm a beginner in learning Python. 
The version of python I'm using is 3.2.1.1 
I'm trying to learn the ctypes by following the tutorial from docs.python.org

in the intereactive prompt,

```
import ctypes
libc = cdll.msvcrt
printf = libc.printf
printf("%d", 42)
```

it should return the value 42
but in my case, it returns 0.
So what's the problem? Thank very much.

---

Now after I add a >>>from ctypes import cdll, the result became shows this

```
>>>from ctypes import *
>>>libc = cdll.msvcrt 
>>>printf = libc.printf 
>>>printf("%d", 42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line1, in <module>
TypeError: 'CDLL' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it should return `2` as the number of bytes written to `stdout`. And it seems to work fine on my Windows installation (after I add the missing `from ctypes import cdll`). Are you using Windows? `msvcrt` is a Windows only DLL.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows. So do you mean from ctypes import cdll is different from import ctypes ? After I add the missing code, it still couldn't work, could you please check for me again?

Comment: that's my entire code. i run this in the interactive prompt(the version is Portable Python 3.2.1.1.) . I try to run this again just now, the result become 0 again...And then I downloaded a Python 2.7.3, and i ran the same code in the Python shell, it did give me 2! why is it so? Thank you for your kindness!

Comment: `printf` returns the number of bytes written. The string `"42"` is 2 bytes long.

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks like it did return the number of bytes written. But why does 'printf' returns that? Shouldn't it return the exact value(like here, the value i expected is '42' I assigned? So how should I return the exact value by using printf?

Comment: `printf` always prints the value to `stdout`. You are looking for `sprintf`. But here comes the real question... Why are you using ctypes for this? Python has this feature built in. Use `x = "%d-%d %s" % (42, 1337, "string")`

Comment: I'm just tryiing to learn the `ctypes` now, my ultimate goal is to control some hardwares by using `ctypes` to interface with the devices' dll... But now I found another way to do this. So your mean if I use `sprintf`, the result will be correct, is it so? But why in the tutorial from Python's official website, the `printf` works.

Comment: I don't know what the tutorial is trying to teach you, but if you want to print a formatted string into another string, and not into `stdout`, then `sprintf` is what you're looking for.